# How to make css Gradients?

Tags: css, gradient

can anyone please help me with this gradients , thanks.
 [This what i was able to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVweT.png)

[and this what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxSLo.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - specifically, include all relevant code/images in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this web site https://cssgradient.io/

you can make the gradient, then, copy the css code  for your background.

Comment: yes i konw , but its hard to work with :/

Comment: @danielashley i don't understand your question.

Comment: sorry  first time here in stackoverflow , so i want to make 3 different gradient as shown in the second image click (and this what i want )